# Django was push in base wrong date

Tags: python, django

Please help!!!
I'm in views have value date by localzone, but in database, the Django was pull date by UTC...
What i'm must do, to push in base date by my local timezone? (my local zone Europe/Kiev)

Please help)))

Answer (score 4):

There are two vairable inside your settings.py

```
# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:             
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name                         
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.           
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same            
# timezone as the operating system.                                             
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your      
# system time zone.                                                             
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.       
USE_TZ = True
```

By setting this two variables you can control how django stores and print dates back.

Answer (score 1):

This is not strictly an answer to your question, but in general the best practice is to store time in UTC and convert it to whatever timezone you want at display time. This way there is less ambiguity about the time.